# How should I pass variable to system() C call?

Tags: c, linux

How should I call System C call if I want to send `echo $c > 1.txt`? I was able to send `c` to `1.txt` but how can I send `$c` (in script sense) in C code (i.e., the value in c)?

My code is something like this:

```
void main() {
    int c =100;
    system("echo c > 1.txt");
}
```

I would like to save 100 in the file `1.txt`

Comment: `echo \$c`? you're firing up a shell, which means shell metachars have to be taken into account.

Comment: For the sake of explanation I gave $c as an example.
My code is something like this:
    void main()
    {
     int c =100;
     system("echo c > 1.txt");
    }
I would like to save 100 in the file 1.txt

Comment: Use `fopen` to open a text file, `fprintf` your data, `fclose` the file.

Comment: [`void main()` is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714) and is a relic from a pre-standard C compiler

Comment: So your question is *How do I write the value of a variable to a file?* instead. You should [edit] to make it clear that's what you're asking (after searching here to see if it's been asked before, of course). You don't *echo* from within an application; that's for use at the command line. You also don't need `system()` here.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function to construct appropriate command and then pass it to your `system()` call:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c = 100;
    char buffer[128];
    sprintf(buffer, "echo %d > 1.txt", c);
    system(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fopen/fwrite/fclose is the proper. But If you want to use shell code then something like below  will work:

```
int main(){
    int c =100;
    char cmd_to_run[256]={'\0'};
    sprintf(cmd_to_run,"echo %d > 1.txt",c);
    system(cmd_to_run);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a system call you can do it like this - prepare the system string first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[42];
    int c = 100;
    sprintf(str, "echo %d > 1.txt", c);
    system(str);
    return 0;
}
```

... but a way to do it in C is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int c = 100;
    FILE *fil;
    fil = fopen("1.txt", "wt");
    if(fil != NULL) {
        fprintf(fil, "%d", c);
        fclose(fil);
    }
    return 0;
}
```